# Automated testing Chrome with selenium and java returns: Failed to create Chrome process

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

When trying to run Selenium on Windows 10 Chrome version 90, I am getting the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00F0C013+2474003]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EA29C1+2042305]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DB2F68+1060712]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DCD9C8+1169864]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DCAA83+1157763]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DFA2A2+1352354]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DF8FAA+1347498]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DF66DB+1337051]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DD3427+1192999]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DD42EE+1196782]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DD4279+1196665]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010996FC+1590332]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01148614+2306900]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F99E93+543699]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F992CE+540686]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EA86BA+2066106]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAD1C8+2085320]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAD308+2085640]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB67F3+2123763]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77726359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D987A4+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D98774+180]
```

Here is the code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
         
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I'm confident that I have the correct version of the Chrome driver(ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24), also the chrome that I am using is 90.0.4430.85.

Does anyone see why this might be happening?

Comment: A quick search reveals such a problem might be related to user permissions (administrator vs normal user). Could you check that, change it around and confirm it's not your case?

Comment: Yes I have checked that chrome is not running as administrator. And I got the same error

Comment: Facing the same issue with Chromedriver version 90.0.4430.24 and Chrome version 90.0.4430.85